# Collision with 2D div's using DOM

Tags: javascript, html

At first: Sorry for my bad english, its hard for me to describe my problems in english :)

In school I have to program my own (simple) js game using ONLY DOM. So far so good, I already did the game control ans some other things. My problem is, to detect a collision between some images/div's. I really dont know how to do that, my teacher can't help me with that. So my problem is, to write a function which detects a collision and evt. returns true. 
I hope anyoe of you can help me!
Greetings Laurin
    My code:`
    
        
        
            IT-BOY
            
            
            
                @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P');

```
    <body id="game" onload="monster1Bewegen()">
    <audio autoplay loop>
        <source src="jarmusik.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <form name="form01">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var elem = document.getElementById('game');
            elem.addEventListener("keydown", KeyPressed );          
        </script>   
        <div id="main">
            <h1 id="h">Dein Leben: </h1>
            <progress value="100" id="p" max="100" min="0"></progress>
            <div id="wiese">
                <div style="width:100%;">
                    <img class="bg_image" id="bgimg01" width="100%" src="C:\Users\Laurin\Desktop\MEDT2\MEDT2\www\01Brein\Modul3\wiese.png">
                </div>
                <img name="character01" id="boy" src="ITboy.gif">
                <img id="sonne" src="sonne.png">
                <img id="erdblock" src="Stehdings.png">
                <img id="monster1" src="monster.gif">
                <img id="gewitter" src="gewitter.png">
                <img id="busch" src="busch.png">
                <img id="erdblock2" src="stehdings.png">
                <img id="wolke" src="stehwolke.png">
                <img id="monster2" src="regenbogenschwein.gif">
                <img id="erdblock3" src="stehdings.png">
                <img id="wolke2" src="stehwolke.png">
                <img id="wolke3" src="stehwolke.png">
                <img id="monster3" src="rosasaurus.gif">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        move("initial");    
    </script>
    </body>
</html>`

    var obj_left = 560;
    var obj_top = 520;
    var steps = 10;
    var characterGround = obj_top + 50;
    var obj_postion = "";
    function move(direction)    {
        if(direction == "initial")  {
            setPos(obj_top,obj_left);   
        }
        else    {
            switch(direction)   {
                case "up":
                    obj_top     -= steps;
                    break;
                case "left":
                    obj_left    -= steps;
                    break;      
                case "right":
                    obj_left    += steps;
                    break;          
                case "down":    //Down - only if character is higher than ground
                    if(obj_top>characterGround) {
                        obj_top     += steps;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            setPos(obj_top,obj_left);
        }

    }

    function setPos(otop,oleft) {
        document.form01.character01.style.position = "absolute";
        document.form01.character01.style.zIndex = "3";
        document.form01.character01.style.top = otop    + "px";
        document.form01.character01.style.left = oleft +    "px";
    }
    function KeyPressed(evt) {
    /**********************************************************
    ****** Important KeyCodes                               ***
    ***********************************************************
    UP Arrow: KeyCode 38
    DOWN Arrow: KeyCode 40
    LEFT Arrow: KeyCode 37
    RIGHT Arrow: KeyCode 39
    SPACE: KeyCode 32
    *********************************************************/
        switch(evt.keyCode) {
            //LEFT
            case 37:
                obj_left -= steps;
                break;
            //RIGHT
            case 39:
                obj_left += steps;
                break;
            //UP 
            case 38:
                bj_top -= steps;
                break;
            //Down
            case 40:
                obj_top     += steps;
                break;
            //Jump - Space
            case 32:
                jump();
                break;
        }
        setPos(obj_top,obj_left);
    }


    /***********************************************************/
    /*      Character Jump                                     */
    /***********************************************************/
    var yVel = 0; //Velocity in the Y Direction (top)
    var gravity = 2; //Gravity
    var isJumping = false; //Saves the state if the character is jumping or not - prevent multiple jumps
    var drop;   

    function jump() {   //If the character isn't already jumping - jump
        if (isJumping == false) {
            yVel = -150;
            obj_top += yVel;
            setPos(obj_top,obj_left);
            isJumping = true;
            droploop();
        }
    }
    function droploop() {
        //if isJumping is true
        if(isJumping)   {
            obj_top += gravity;
            setPos(obj_top,obj_left);       
            //Check if the character has reached the ground the drop is stopped
            if (obj_top > characterGround)  {               
                obj_top = characterGround;
                setPos(obj_top,obj_left);
                yVel = 0;
                isJumping = false;
                clearInterval(drop);        
            }   
            else    {
                //if the character has not reached the ground the loop for the drop is started
                drop = setInterval(droploop, 500);
            }
        }
    }       
    /***********************************************************/
    /* Set Szene                                               */
    /***********************************************************/
    var x = 830;
    var left = false;
    function monster1Bewegen()  {
        if(x>=810 && x<=900){
            if(left)
                x--;
            else
                x++;
        }
        if(x == 810 || x == 900)    {
            left = !left;
        }
        document.getElementById('monster1').style.left = x + "px";
        window.setTimeout(monster1Bewegen, 30);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this here is demo https://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/TG2M7/

```
function getPositions(box) {
 var $box = $(box);
 var pos = $box.position();
 var width = $box.width();
 var height = $box.height();
 return [ [ pos.left, pos.left + width ], [ pos.top, pos.top + height ] 
 ];
 }

function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
 var x1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
 var x2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
 return x1[1] > x2[0] || x1[0] === x2[0] ? true : false;
 }

function checkCollisions(){
var box = $(".bomb")[0];
var pos = getPositions(box);

var pos2 = getPositions(this);
var horizontalMatch = comparePositions(pos[0], pos2[0]);
var verticalMatch = comparePositions(pos[1], pos2[1]);            
var match = horizontalMatch && verticalMatch;
if (match) { $("body").append("<p>COLLISION !!!</p>"); }
}
```